# flutter doctor after install

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm following the setup guide [here](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path) and after I unzip flutter and run `flutter doctor` I get the following error

```
flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale en-US)
⣾Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
#0      List.[] (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:145:60)
#1      IntelliJValidatorOnMac.pluginsPath (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:666:31)
#2      IntelliJValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:509:53)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:112:52)
#4      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:185:41)
#5      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#6      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:175:24)
#7      DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:48:39)
#8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#9      DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:34:42)
#10     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:526:18)
#11     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#17     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#18     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#19     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#22     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

I've tried installing flutter from git, trying different channels, setting my path, downloading dart, downloading flutter/dart for android studio and I can not get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is causing the issue but a fresh install of Git and sdk may resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused due to dart. Try the following steps:

1) Running `flutter packages get` in your terminal would be a good idea

2) Run `flutter upgrade` in your terminal

3) Check if dart is installed by running `dart --version`

4) Check if you have brew by running `which brew`

5) Also check the if you're on the dev channel or not, some people experience issues on dev channel. If you are, I'd suggest switching to master.

In case you don't have dart installed, I'd suggest installing dart. Hope this helps. Do let us know if something works.

Comment: I ended up reformatting my mac and reinstalling osx. Nothing would work otherwise

Comment: Yes that fixed it. But I wouldn't advise for everyone to do it. I was lucky and that computer was sitting unused for a few months so I didn't care about the contents on it